# j(render(@partial)) returns error: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render a partial with ajax, but for some reason it returns this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat in ThingsController#upvoterandom
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I'm very confused because I accomplished something with an essentially identical format before, and I never had any problems with it. Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? I can render a string with the ajax; it's only when I try to render a partial that I get the error. By the way, I achieved this error by deleting the `format.html` line and then visiting the `upvoterandom_thing` path directly in my browser.

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<div id= "randomajax" >
    <div id="randajax">
      <%= link_to @rand.name, thing_path(@rand) %>
      <%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.jpg", class: "rand_up_vote"), remote: true, %>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function reload_script() {
            $(".rand_up_vote").click(function () {
              $.get( "<%= upvoterandom_thing_path(:id => @rand.id) %>", function( data ) {
              });
            });
        }
        reload_script();
      </script> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**controllers/things_controller.rb** I put asterisks around the line highlighted with the error.

```
def upvoterandom
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  #...
  ***respond_to do |format|***
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**views/things/upvoterandom.js.erb:** .html("test") returns "test", so the problem has to be in the rendering.

```
$('#randomajax').html("<%= j(render(@randajax)) %>");
```

**views/things/_randajax.html.erb**

```
TEST
```

---

**THIS IS THE OTHER NEAR-IDENTICAL AJAX STRUCTURE THAT WORKS:**

---

**views/things/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@thing, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :text %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", id: "postacomment" %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/comments_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])
  @comment = @thing.comments.create(comment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to root_path }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**views/comments/create.js.erb**

```
$('#comments_h2').prepend("<%= j(render(@comment)) %>");
```

**views/comments/_comment.html.erb**

```
TEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I haven't figured out why the syntax I was trying wasn't working, but this syntax does work:

```
$('#randomajax').html("<%= render 'randajax' %>");
```

Comment: isn't that the same answer that i provided?

Comment: And I don't know what `switched to ruby instead of javascript` even means. You've simply not escaped JavaScript in this version and provided a path to the partial for `render` method instead of a `nil` value.

Comment: I tried your syntax but it didn't work. I'm using the ruby render method instead of j(render), which I assumed was short for javascript(render).

Comment: Nope. 'j' is an alias for 'escape_javascript' as you can read here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html Follow that link to see how certain characters are treated when you `j(render(view_path))`. Since you're rendering the output through JavaScript's html() function, you might in fact need `j(render` instead of just `render`. I'm clarifying this for you as well as for future searchers who stumble upon here. And I'm curious: was my answer still returning the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I don't know why your syntax didn't work. Yes, it returns the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I'll apologize up front for the long answer. I've tried reproducing your issue in multiple ways, but I think you might be looking in the wrong direction. I've included the entire story so you can see if it all matches up, and if it doesn't it hopefully leads to insights which will help you resolve the issue.

### `ActionController::UnknownFormat` happens before view rendering

If Rails presents you with the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error, it means that your controller does not respond to the format that is being requested. The error is raised by the `respond_to` method, at the exact line you highlighted.

Had an error been raised during view rendering, then it would have been bubbled up through either the line with `format.html` or `format.js`. So this error is certainly not caused in the view rendering part.

### Reproducing the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error

The only way I can get the exact error message you posted, is if I request the AJAX response page directly in the browser. Then you see the Rails error page, which will also show you which format the request was done with. You're probably requesting the page with a format other than `html` or `js`, in which case the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error is triggered, since your controller *only* responds to the `html` or `js` format.

I think the actual issue is hiding somewhere else.

### Reproducing from `views/things/show.html.erb`

I have tried to reproduce the error from the `views/things/show.html.erb` page as well. When doing this with your original code, I get a syntax error on the following line:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("UpArrowGray.jpg", class: "rand_up_vote"), remote: true, %>
```

This happens due to the comma after `remote: true`. Because of this, I assume you haven't been constantly testing with the remote link. When testing it without the `remote: true`, the `reload_script` function triggers a jQuery AJAX request. You're doing this with the following line:

```
$.get( "<%= upvoterandom_thing_path(:id => @rand.id) %>", function( data ) {
});
```

This actually triggers an XHR request with the format `*/*`. It basically tells Rails that any format will do. Here's what happens:

1. The `ThingsController` responds with the first format you've defined in the `respond_to` block, which is the HTML format. This triggers a redirect to your root path.
2. jQuery follows the redirect, again using the `*/*` format.
3. The controller at your root path responds with the first defined format, or HTML by default if no `respond_to` block is present.
4. jQuery then loads that response.

There's no way that the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` could have been raised from `ThingsController` when reproducing it like this.

### What I think

This is mostly guessing work, so please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. You clicked the upvote remote link and nothing visibly happened.
2. You added a JavaScript to explictly fetch the page through AJAX, but still nothing visibly happened.
3. You visited the `things/1/upvoterandom.js` (or alike) page directly with your browser. In this case an `ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest` would have been raised.
4. You visited the `things/1/upvoterandom.json` (I used JSON, but it could be any format other than HTML or JS) page directly with your browser, and you got the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.

If this is how it happened, you need to go back to step 1, and start reproducing the issue in another direction:

1. Go to the `things/1` (or another Thing ID) page.
2. Open up the Developer Tools/Web Inspector of your browser.
3. Go to the view which shows the network communication (in Chrome this is the tab called Network).
4. Now click the link, and see what communication happens between your browser and your Rails application. If a lot happens, you often can filter for XHR only, which only show AJAX requests.
5. If you see a 500 status popping up there, you need to check the Rails server output for an error with stacktrace.

I can only guess what the actual cause of the issue is, but I think it might actually be some error when rendering the view, As you said, the only case where it doesn't work is if you render the partial. I hope this information helps you to resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't know if this is *right* but it's awesome detective work.

Comment: I figured out I can just use ruby to render the partial instead of javascript. But I'll award you the bounty anyway, because as pjmorse said, this is great detective work. You were dead on with your assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

In `views/things/upvoterandom.js.erb` you're trying to render `@randajax` like so:

```
$('#randomajax').html("<%= j(render(@randajax)) %>");
```

But I don't see `@randajax` being assigned anywhere, which means that it's `nil`.

Trying to render `nil` is the cause of this issue. But do confirm this by doing the following the first:

```
$('#randomajax').html("<%= j(render(nil)) %>");
```

If it returns the same error, then we've found the culprit.

Either assign `@randajax` something prior to rendering it or simply use:

```
$('#randomajax').html("<%= j(render(path_to_partial)) %>");
```